# How to send a POST request with parameters to an endpoint via JBoss HttpRouter?

Tags: java, jboss, httprequest, esb

I'm working on an ESB project and I need to call a REST service using a POST request. HttpRouter seems to be the right way to do it since it supports both GET and POST methods but I can't find a way to inject parameters inside my call.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer... It was pretty dumb. All you need to do is to inject parameters inside the Message object and they will be in the body of the request. Here is a sample code created by JBoss and found from a unit test of HttpRouter :

```
    final ConfigTree tree = new ConfigTree("WrappedMessage");
    tree.setAttribute("endpointUrl", "http://127.0.0.1:8080/esb-echo");
    tree.setAttribute("method", "post");
    tree.setAttribute("unwrap", "false");
    tree.setAttribute("MappedHeaderList", "SOAPAction, Content-Type, Accept, If-Modified-Since");

    HttpRouter router = new HttpRouter(tree);
    Message message = MessageFactory.getInstance().getMessage(type);
    message.getBody().add("bar");

    Message response = router.process(message);
    String responseBody = (String)response.getBody().get();
    String responseStr = null;
    if (deserialize)
        responseStr = Encoding.decodeToObject(responseBody).toString();
    else
        responseStr = responseBody;

    return responseStr;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Apache HTTP library](http://hc.apache.org/index.html). It's very easy to use and have comprehensive set of class needed to manipulate HTTP request.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but actually JBoss HttpRouter relies on Apache HTTP Library. I know how to do it with a PostMethod object. What I'm looking for is how to pass parameters with HttpRouter.